# lightning:datatable set columns dynamicaly

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-datatable

```
init: function (cmp, event, helper) {


var columns = '[{"label": "Rank", "fieldName": "rank", "type": "text","initialWidth": "70"},{"label": "Advocate", "fieldName": "advocateName", "type": "text", "initialWidth": "150"},{"label": "Company", "fieldName": "company", "type": "text", "initialWidth": "150"},{"label": "References", "fieldName": "references", "type": "text", "initialWidth": "70"},{"label": "Action", "type": "button", "typeAttributes": { "label": "Recommend", "name": "recommend", "title": "Click to Recommend"} }]';

console.log(columns);
var jsonColumns = JSON.parse(columns);
console.log(jsonColumns);
cmp.set('v.mycolumns', jsonColumns);

cmp.set('v.mydata', [{
                rank: '1',
                advocateName: 'Avery Faulkner',
                company: 'Test',
                references: '0'
            },
            {
                rank: '2',
                advocateName: 'Test Adv',
                company: 'Test Adv',
                references: '0'
     }]);
}
```

Component

```
<lightning:datatable data="{! v.mydata }"
                     columns="{! v.mycolumns }"
                     keyField="id"
                     onrowselection="{! c.getSelectedName }"
                     onrowaction="{! c.handleRowAction }"
                     hideCheckboxColumn="true"/>
```

Why I have only one column in datatable?

[image]

Comment: Can you post your lightning:datatable construct also please?

Comment: @Kal added component with datatable creation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `initialWidth` is an integer property and you have provided the value as text.

Once you provide the columns like this

```
var columns = '[{"label": "Advocate", "fieldName": "advocateName", "type": "text", "initialWidth": 150},...
```

it starts working.